# NSDictionary for loop exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary

I've a method with this part of code:

```
NSDictionary *tmpDict = [self getJsonDictionary];

NSInteger tmpID;

for (NSDictionary *d in tmpDict) {
    tmpID = [[d objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
}
```

`tmpDict` is a NSDictionary with variable size. If `tmpDict` contains at least 2 objects (2 NSDictionary) it works well but if it contains only 1 object (1 NSDictionary) throws this exception:

```
 -[NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e866d0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e866d0'
```

Why this? And how to fix if `tmpDict` has only 1 object?

Probably `for (NSDictionary *d in tmpDict)` is the problem and when `tmpDict` has 1 object `d` is a `NSCFString`, but why?

-- **UPDATE**

The problem is when `tmpDict` has 1 item (one NSDictionary) the `for (NSDictionary *d in tmpDict)` take every key/value item in the dictionary and this is the reason for exception. Otherwise if `tmpDict` has 2+ items is a NSDictionary of NSDictionary and it works well. I need a way to fix this still using the for loop. Ideas?

-- **UPDATE 2***

Actually this code works but it's redundant:

```
if ([tmpObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    tmpID = [[tmpObject objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
    tmpProp2 = [tmpObject objectForKey:@"prop2"];
    tmpProp3 = [tmpObject objectForKey:@"prop3"];
    tmpProp4 = [tmpObject objectForKey:@"prop4"];
} else if ([tmpObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    for (NSDictionary *d in tmpObject) {
        tmpID = [[d objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
        tmpProp2 = [d objectForKey:@"prop2"];
        tmpProp3 = [d objectForKey:@"prop3"];
        tmpProp4 = [d objectForKey:@"prop4"];
    }
}
```

It needs an improvement.

Comment: WRT Update 2: the only improvement is that you could factor out getting the items from the dictionary. Otherwise, that looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised it works at all actually.  For dictionaries, fast enumeration enumerates the **keys**.  That's why it's telling you that `-objectForKey:` has been sent to an `NSCFString` because the key of a dictionary coming from JSON is always a string.

You should, perhaps, do this:

```
for (id d in [tmpDict objectEnumerator])
{
    // Objects in a JSON dictionary aren't necessarily dictionaries
    if([d isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
         tmpID = [[d objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
    }
}
```

---

One possible reason why it might work with two dictionaries is if the top level item is actually an array, not a dictionary.  If you have:

```
[ { "id" : 1 }, { "id" : 2 } ]
```

your JSON parser will give you an `NSArray`, not an `NSDictionary`, which can be parsed with your code even though you assume your top level item is a dictionary.

**Edit:** Having seen your update, I'm sure this is what is happening.  If you have one object, your JSON string is looking like:

```
{ "id" : 1, "prop2" : "value1", "prop3" : "value1", "prop4" : "value1" }
```

If you have two objects, it probably looks like:

```
[
        { "id" : 1, "prop2" : "value1", "prop3" : "value1", "prop4" : "value1" },
        { "id" : 2, "prop2" : "value1", "prop3" : "value1", "prop4" : "value1" }
]
```

Notice the square brackets, that means JSON array.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you explain me why you use `objectEnumerator`? Checkout my new update.

Comment: @Fred: because objectEnumerator returns the objects instead of the keys when you do fast enumeration on it.

Comment: @Fred: your latest update is consistent with my speculation in the second part of my answer.  If you have one dictionary, your JSON is that one dictionary, if you have more than one dictionary your JSON is an array of the dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

The error is occurring because there is an object of type NSString in your tmpDict variable, so you can use this.

```
 for (id *d in tmpDict)
{
    if([d isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        tmpID = [[d objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
    else
        tmpID = [(NSString *)d intValue];
}
```

instead of this

```
for (NSDictionary *d in tmpDict) {
    tmpID = [[d objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
}
```

Comment: It's ok but I need to take `tmpID = [[tmpDict objectForKey@"id"] integerValue]` if d is not a NSDictionary (if tmpDict has only 1 item I still need to take objects but I should use `[tmpDict objectForkey]`

Comment: This works but if in the NSDictionary there are more then one key/value pair the else block is repeat.

Comment: you can have a check at the end of the for loop to check if the tmpID value is updated or not, if yes then do not change is value.